# Instance of subset sum problem

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, np-complete

I have a problem which is a pretty clear instance of the subset sum problem:

"given a list of Integers in the range [-65000,65000], the function returns true if any subset of the list summed is equal to zero. False otherwise."

What I wanted to ask is more of an explanation than a solution.

This was an instance-specific solution I came up before thinking about the complexity of the problem.

- Sort the array A[] and, during sort, sum each element to a counter 'extSum' (O(NLogN))
- Define to pointers low = A[0] and high = A[n-1]
- Here is the deciding code:
- ```
  while(A[low]<0){
    sum = extSum;
    if(extSum>0){
      while(sum - A[high] < sum){
          tmp = sum - A[high];
          if(tmp==0) return true;
          else if(tmp > 0){
              sum = tmp;
              high--;
          }
          else{
              high--;
          }
      }
      extSum -= A[low];
      low++;
      high = n - 1;
    }
    else{
      /* Symmetric code: switch low, high and the operation > and < */
    }
  }
  return false;
  ```

First of all, is this solution correct? I made some tests, but I am not sure...it looks too easy...
Isn't the time complexity of this code O(n^2)?

I already read the various DP solutions and the thing I would like to understand is, for the specific instance of the problem I am facing, how much better than this naive and intuitive solution they are. I know my approach can be improved a lot but nothing that would make a big difference when it comes to the time complexity....

Thank you for the clarifications

**EDIT:** One obvious optimization would be that, while sorting, if a 0 is found, the function returns true immediately....but it's only for the specific case in which there are 0s in the array.

Comment: If I understand your code properly, aren't you assuming the subset will be contiguous? This isn't necessarily the case

Comment: @isbadawi: well, I just assume it's gonna be sorted, and this is because I sort it as a first step.

Comment: I mean e.g. what if your input is [-4, 1, 4]. A solution is {-4, 4}, but you won't find it

Comment: @isbadawi: I think it does find it... if the input is [-4,1,4], then extSum will be 1.
the first run of the inner while will only decrement high (because 1 - 4 < 0) and the second will return 0: 1 - A[1] = 0....
No?

Comment: I only have to return True or False, not the actual subsets....

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I think {0} will beat your answer.

Because it will simply ignore while and return false.

Comment: Well, yes, that is true. But it is such a specific case I didn't even mention it.
Actually, when I say "I know my approach can be improved a lot", the first optimization I think of is that, while I sort the array, if I find any 0 I can immediately return true.

Comment: Well, i think if you do dp you don't have to sort. Consider an array saving sums from negative numbers only and an array saving sums positive only. Only you have to do is to test if there is an sum equals each other. But it is still O(N^2), the only advantage here is you need no sort.

Comment: probably true, but being that the sorting complexity is O(NlogN) and DP complexity is higher, sorting is probably not the bottleneck here....right?

Comment: well, This may failed {-4,-3,-2,6}?

Comment: Well you can use only one array. if only negative gives the sum you plus 1, if positive nums give the sum you plus 2, The numbers equal 3 in the array is your answer. Two arrays are simple for giving the idea.

Comment: it would work...only it would enter the branch of the "if" which is symmetric to the one I showed in the example...
    if(extSum>0){
    else{
        /* your example would enter this branch */

Comment: It looks like your algorithm is a greedy one? I just think your algorithm will only take -4, 6, -3 and fail. If you are using a greedy algorithm for this problem, fail in such tricky data is going to happen.